# Omit interval / split scales on axis? Fine grained for low and high interval?

Tags: r, intervals

Assuming I have two data sets I'd like to plot in one plot.

For instance something like this:

```
low <- runif(10,min=10, max=50)
high <- runif(10,min=10000, max=11000)
plot(
     high,
     type="l",
     ylim=c(0,11000)
)
lines(low, type="l")
```

I dont want the y-axis to show all values in between these samples because the way it is, the `low` data would appear as flat line, even though there are variations.

Therefore, the axis should have a finer grained ticks between 10-50, and should omit values between 50 and 10000. Then again, the interval [10000-11000] should have finer grained ticks, too. Thus, variations for the `low` sample are also visible.

Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

If found this, bt

Answer (score 1):

Could this be useful...?

```
set.seed(001)    
low <- runif(10,min=10, max=50)

high <- runif(10,min=10000, max=11000)
plot(
  high,
  type="l",
  ylim=c(0,11000)
)
lines(low, type="l")


plot(high,            
     type="l",              
     col="red",              
     bty='l',                
     ylab='', xlab='',      
     las=1,                 
     cex.axis=.75)     

par(new=TRUE)                

plot(low,
     type="l", 
     col="blue", 
     bty='n',                
     xaxt="n",               
     yaxt="n",               
     xlab="", ylab="", 
     cex.axis=.75)

axis(4, las=1, cex.axis=.75) 

legend('topright', c('high', 'low'), col=c('red', 'blue'), lty=1, bty='n', cex=.75)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Questions of good graphical practice aside, this can be done using the **plotrix** package:

```
low <- runif(10,min=10, max=50)
high <- runif(10,min=10000, max=11000)
y <- c(low,high)
x <- rep(1:10,times = 2)

library(plotrix)
yl <- c(pretty(5:70,2),pretty(9900:11000,5))
gap.plot(x,y,
        gap = c(70,9900),
        gap.axis = "y",
        ytics = yl,
        type = "l")
```

[image]